# Compile leveldb c++ program in linux error?

Tags: c++, linux, database, leveldb

I have install leveldb in my home directory `~/local` like this.

```
[~/temp/leveldb-1.15.0] $ make
[~/temp/leveldb-1.15.0] $ cp -av libleveldb.* $HOME/local/lib/
[~/temp/leveldb-1.15.0] $ cp -av include/leveldb $HOME/local/include/
```

My c++ program like this：

```
#include <assert.h> 
#include <iostream> 
#include "leveldb/db.h" 

using namespace std; 

int main(int argc,char * argv[]) 
{ 
leveldb::DB* db; 
leveldb::Options options; 
options.create_if_missing = true; 
std::string dbpath = "tdb"; 
leveldb::Status status = leveldb::DB::Open(options, dbpath, &db); 
assert(status.ok()); 
std::string key1 = "grz"; 
std::string key2 = "grz-rt@63.com"; 
cout<<"Open db OK"<<std::endl; 

std::string value; 
leveldb::Status s ; 
s = db->Put(leveldb::WriteOptions(), key1, key2);/*key1和key2作为一对key-value对插入*/ 
s = db->Get(leveldb::ReadOptions(), key1, &value);/*根据key返回对应的value值*/ 

cout<<value<<std::endl; 
delete db;/*删除数据库*/ 

return 0; 
}
```

I compile this C++ program like this：

```
g++ -o Main Main.cpp ~/local/lib/libleveldb.a -lpthread -I ~/local/include/
```

But I get the error like this：

```
/public/home/kli/local/lib/libleveldb.a(table_builder.o): In function `leveldb::TableBuilder::WriteBlock(leveldb::BlockBuilder*, leveldb::BlockHandle*)':
table_builder.cc:(.text+0x678): undefined reference to `snappy::MaxCompressedLength(unsigned long)'
table_builder.cc:(.text+0x6b2): undefined reference to `snappy::RawCompress(char const*, unsigned long, char*, unsigned long*)'
/public/home/kli/local/lib/libleveldb.a(format.o): In function `leveldb::ReadBlock(leveldb::RandomAccessFile*, leveldb::ReadOptions const&, leveldb::BlockHandle const&, leveldb::BlockContents*)':
format.cc:(.text+0x5de): undefined reference to `snappy::GetUncompressedLength(char const*, unsigned long, unsigned long*)'
format.cc:(.text+0x64e): undefined reference to `snappy::RawUncompress(char const*, unsigned long, char*)'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I don't know what's wrong.

I am new to Linux. Thank you very much!

Comment: You don't need root to compile something in your own home directory.

Comment: You are missing some `-I` ... flags in your compilation command. Perhaps `-I ~/local/include` ... Try compiling with `g++ -Wall -H -I ~/local/include/`

Comment: Is `leveldb/iterator.h` the relative path to your file ?

Comment: cp -av include/leveldb $HOME/local/include/leveldb would solve the issue

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`libleveldb.a` misses Snappy when being linked which would be probably in `libsnappy.a` in the same directory.

Comment: Thank you very much. I compile it like this. `g++ -o Main Main.cpp ~/local/lib/libleveldb.a ~/local/lib/libsnappy.a -lpthread -I ~/local/include/
`. Everything is ok.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the `Makefile` is incomplete.

With the current install, you need to edit the Makefile to link against `snappy` and to include `-L/usr/local/lib` instead of `-L/usr/local/include`.

(Will post pull request later)